# Docker for deploying djano application

Tags: django, docker, nginx, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have seen some pages with title deploy django with docker .

I deploy just with nginx & gunicorn and its awesome .

Is docker good for deploying django app ?

Does it make application faster or with better performance ?

So whats the main purpose ?

Answer (score 1):

Docker helps developers bring their ideas to life by conquering the complexity of app development. It packages your Django app and creates a run time making sure that it works the same on all machines.

> "But, It works on my system" - Developer without docker!

Also, you might be using nginx and gunicorn with Docker as well for hosting your django app. Containerization is a generic concept to have a machine independent run time to package everything. It simplifies your deployment process.